# Help guys android feature problem

Tags: applications

**when I try to install an application in my phone it's (*tecno pop 2 plus* )**it does not require the notification access option. It responses that *that this feature is not in this device*

Comment: I am sorry but based on what you have written it is neither clear what your question is nor what you are speaking about. Please edit your question and explain in detail what you are trying to to and what does not work.

Comment: Android Go doesn't support Notification Access. The only way to access this setting is by leaving Android Go.